# Macports won't install

Tags: php, mysql, macos, pdo, macports

So I'm trying to install the PDO drivers via Macports. I am using `install php5-mysql`, but when I hit enter I get

```
usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
           [-o owner] file1 file2
   install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
           [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
   install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...
```

I'm not really sure were to go from here. Any ideas?

Comment: Any reason you can't just roll with MAMP?

Comment: It always messes up, and it won't start up sometimes. @Zarathuztra

Comment: There are logs for that

Comment: There's also [`Homebrew`](http://brew.sh/) if that's an option...

Comment: Or I could just use `sudo php -S localhost:80 -t` and have a PHP server running almost instantly. @Zarathuztra

Comment: @user302975 That's not a full stack solution, isn't all that much quicker than a working version of mamp, and is bound to cause you headaches because of the way Mac OS plays with services.

Comment: I like extreme flexibility, and I spend most of my time in the command line, so it doesn't really bother me. Until sometime break....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, it appears that you are using another *(possibly built-in)* `install` command rather than the MacPorts command `port install`.

According to [the documentation](https://guide.macports.org/#using.port.install), you may need to use `sudo` in front of the `port install` command, as well, like this:

```
sudo port install ...
```

*(where ... is the name of what you are going to install via MacPorts)*

Comment: I am using `sudo`. And when I use `sudo port install php5-mysql` I get `Error: Processing of port php5-mysql failed`.

Comment: @user302975 Ah, it might be a good idea to add that new error information into your original question... it also might be good to let us know what system/environment you are using with this setup, etc.